# Getting data from output

Tags: angular, components, output, parent-child, data-sharing

I have npm called ngx-snake. I would like to collect data about points. In documentation has been written

```
#### Outputs

Name  | Description
--- | ---
foodEaten | Called whenever our sweet snake gained some weight ;)
gameOver | :( collision! snake didn't make it (remember about reset button)
```

so in my component.html I write

```
    <div class="container-user">
      <ngx-snake (foodEaten)="showResult($event)"></ngx-snake>
    </div>
```

and in component.html

```
  showResult(points: any): void {
    console.log(points++);
  }
```

But in fact there is no information about points. It shows another game-grid. I tried also change  to 



 but it also not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am late to the party but still the first one :)
Have you managed to figure it out?

The library itself is not giving you any information about points... you just get info about event that might be useful in implementing your own scores system.

The lib was developed to assist in angular learning so... there is bunch of things that you have to do with it yourself

best!

Answer (score 0):

yeah, im also late but anyways..

whats happening here is that you are actullay passing an event to your
function and not the score itself, so get the event and check it to see what iti usefull to you and keep that info!